# Joining two tables with composite key

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I put my hands on a very old legacy DB-based application (ie. MySQL) which has two tables for mapping invoices: let's call them INVOICE_HEADER and INVOICE_ROWS.

Well, the ideal scenario would obviously be an `@Id Long id;` in the **Invoice** entity and a bi-directional @OnetoMany + @ManyToOne relationship, mapped by a FK_HEADER foreign key in the INVOICE_ROWS table. The normal JPA way to map such type of relationship.

However that table (the header one) has **four** (yes, four!) columns as a composite primary key (year,number,t1,t2), as well as the rows table. The app is using those four columns to make a manual JOIN between the two tables.
No foreign key constraints at all.

Unfortunately, the schema is unchangeable at all.
How will I write my two JPA entities?
I think this is the use case for an @IdClass (or @EmbeddedId?).

Is it possible to have a @OneToMany relationship mapped by a composite key?
Can you help me with some examples? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible and shouldn't be difficult at all- ORMs JPA is based off of are designed to be flexible solutions.  The ID JPA uses doesn't even have to be the pk used in the database; the only restriction is that it should be unique.  JPA 2 included support for derived IDs which might help since I assume the pk for the INVOICE_ROWS is a combination of the INVOICE_HEADER FKs and some other field.  If it has its own sequence, then it simplifies it a bit.

You pick which of the options you want to use - IdClass or caching the id class within the entity as an EmbeddedId.  My preference usually is IdClass as I don't use the class much.  So a simple example would be:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(HeaderPK.class)
class Header {
  @Id
  java.sql.Date year;
  @Id
  Integer number;
  @Id
  String t1;
  @Id
  String t2;
  @OneToMany(mappedby="header")
  List<Row> rows;
}

class HeaderPK {
  java.sql.Date year;
  Integer number;
  String t1;
  String t2;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(RowPK.class)
class Row {
  @Id
  String someField;
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="YEAR", referencedColumnName="YEAR"),
      @JoinColumn(name="NUMBER", referencedColumnName="NUMBER"),
      @JoinColumn(name="T1", referencedColumnName="T1"),
      @JoinColumn(name="T2", referencedColumnName="T2"),
  })
  Header header;
}

class RowPK {
  String someField;
  HeaderPK header;
}
```

Each of the JoinColumn annotations define the foreign key fields and which primary key fields they point to.  JPA has one restriction in that foreign keys must go to primary key fields - I believe this is to allow for entity caching, as they are cached on their primary keys.  Many providers have ways around this restriction if needed.

If your Row entity has a single primary key, you can do way with the RowPk class.